# Resizing a JPanel with resampling to preserve content

Tags: java, swing, resize, panel, jpanel

Give that I have written a `JPanel` with many different components on it, is there a way to apply an overall "dilate" ability on the panel so that everything in it stretches proportionally when I resize my window?

That is, if I manually resize my window to be 1/4 the size, everything in the panel should also shrink by 1/4 so the new panel is just a dilation of the first.  Given that I have not designed the individual components inside to do this (there are many) is there any easy way to make the panel behave this way?

**UPDATE**: In order to be more clear on the solution I need, I will describe the panel contents:

The panel is a "game" of sorts, with a single null-layout and dozens of ImageIcons flying around the screen at any time.  The ImageIcons are preloaded PNG files, which already have a permanent size.  Of course, I could manually resize each ImageIcon and reposition them relative to window size, but that would involve recoding many components.

There are no buttons or text to worry about, so what I'm really looking for is some kind of "postprocessed" resize where the panel simply shrinks whatever's rendered by some porportion (think of resizing an image in Photoshop).

Comment: +1, great question. I did this "manually" once by adjusting the sizes of the components and adjusting the font sizes through the Look-and-Feel on each resize-event. Horrible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is of course to give up swing all together and use some 3rd party widget component library which draws itself using any `Graphics`. Then you can either draw the widgets on the image and resize the image, or, better yet, apply a transform to the graphics object you pass to the library.

If you do want to stick with swing there is the [`SwingUtilities.paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Container,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method, which you could use to paint the `Panel` onto a `BufferedImage` which you could then resize. (I've used this myself to do some nice transitions between "views" in a game.)

The problem is of course that you somehow need to translate the user input accordingly. I have no solution for this right now, but the above perhaps helps you in some way.

Comment: Well, it turns out there is no direct user input on the panel itself (there is another UI for that).  Perhaps painting onto the BufferedImage will work!  Can you give some hints towards the code?

Comment: IIRC there's not much to it actually. 1) Create a buffered image of the desired dimensions. 2) do getGraphics, cast it to Graphics2D if necessary, 3) call graphics.scale so the painting will be scaled to fit the buffered image 4) pass the graphics object (along with the panel you want to have painted) to the paintComponent method I linked to, and voila, you should have the panel painted on the buffered image which the graphics object paints on.

Answer (score 1):

Using layout managers instead of absolute positioning of the widgets will give you this behaviour. See the oracle tutorials: [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Do you really want fonts to resize on resize events? I don't know a layout manager which will do that for you.

Comment: Resizable layouts are not what I'm looking for: the panel in question is a "game" of sorts--it contains many ImageIcons flying around in a null-layout but provides no easy way to resize the window (since the ImageIcons are preloaded PNG files).  Is there a way to "postprocess" some kind of resizing operation to just dilate the panel and its contents?

Comment: ok, that was not clear to me. I had a standard GUI with buttons etc in my mind when I read your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override `paintChildren()` method of the panel and scale graphics to achieve desired visible size.

Answer (score 1):

You could try J(X)Layer, see http://www.pbjar.org/blogs/jxlayer/jxlayer40/

Comment: Neat demo. Really buggy on my computer though. Perhaps it's some quirk in my JRE. :P